# Swap and save background color with jquery

Tags: javascript, colors, background, hover, swap

I have a menu where on every hover of its links the background color of my page changes.
Now, let's say that my default index.html color is blue, and when I hover on about and contact I have yellow and red.
If I click on the about page its background color will be yellow, and if I hover on home it will go back blue.
What happens is when I mouseOut back to the page, the background changed to blue again, same if I'd hovered on contact.

Here there's my code in JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about').hover(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }, function() {
      $('body').css('background', '');
    });
    $('#contact').hover(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
    }, function() {
      $('body').css('background', '');
    });
```

And here there is the menu

```
 <a id="about" href="about.html">about</a>
 <a id="contact" href="contact.html">contact</a>
```

I assume I should do something like check if the current background color matches the hovered one, on mouseOut keep that color, otherwise set it to the initial one.

I'm not an expert of JS, especially when it comes to conditions.
Anybody could help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color to stay the same after hovering, then you should remove the second parameter of hover():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#about').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  });
  $('#contact').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/as9jpopd/

** EDIT **

If you want the color only to change when the user moves the mouse over the link and then back, then your code should work, only that closing brackets are missing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#about').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
  });
  $('#contact').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
  }, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to stay the same of hovering.
If the page is supposed to be yellow, when hovering the color changes but when I mouseOut goes back to yellow.
Since I declared the color of the homepage with CSS, when I mouseOut CSS resets the color to the general CSS body one (blue) and not to yellow anymore..

Every page has is own color, and the homepage is blue and declared with CSS..when I'm on a page that is supposed to be yellow, it's yellow when it loads, but then my JS resets the color to ' ' meaning blue..

Comment: Basically when I mouseOut the color should be the one declared initially with CSS just for that specific page, not the body background color..
It's like the body bg color has no color, but every page has its own bg color

Comment: Then the code you gave should just work. Only that you didn't copy the closing brackets. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It still does not work!

My CSS has body {background-color: blue;}
My page about.html should be yellow, which is the one that is defined on the hover of the link as well.
When I'm in my page about.html the background is already yellow, as defined with HTML, but when I hover on any link, it switches to no color, as CSS declares 'background', ' '

I need to declare a background-color per each page, and when I mouseOut the background goes back in the one defined in each page, and not in the JS, as the value ' ' would reset the background-color to transparent/none

Comment: Hey Joachim would be will to help me out?
I basically have to create a condition that says if the bg-color is the same of the hovered link, keep it like this, otherwise change it to the original one of when the page was loaded, and have an array where I save all the colors for each loaded page.
I'm not really good with conditions so maybe you could help me? Would be great!

Comment: How is the initial color of the page set? Directly with `style="..."` or with a css class? In the latter case, you could just remove the direct style: `$('body').attr('style', null);`

Comment: For each page is different, so it's declared in the style="" of the body of the page.
I've to change it and reset it on mouse hover/out with the one of the links in the menu

Comment: Now with my new code it doesn't change the color on the hover so I can't test if it works or not in its totality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joachim, but unfortunately that did not work. I uploaded an early stage of the website so you can take a look at the problem and the behaviour of the bg. http://mircofragomena.com/

As you see on the front page the bg is white, but when you hover changes. If you click on pickabrew, you will see the page in yellow as when hovered, but if you go again on the menu hover/out, the page goes back in white as the front page. It should stay yellow though, as it should happen with every other color/page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using this other code

```
      $(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  var bg = body.css('background-color');
  $('ul.nav a').hover(function() {
              body.css('background-color', $(this).data('bgColor'));
        }, function() {
              body.css('background-color', bg);
        });
```

});

related with this one on the links

```
              <li><a href="../posters/index.html" data-bgColor="#F2C40D">Posters</a></li>
```

though it does not work.
Is this a good starting code?